# Jqgrid filter toolbar clear search sets wrong default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

We have JqGrid version 5.2.1. we have functionality to reorder columns and filter toolbar with default values.

whenever we drag and drop a column having default value to another column it works well but when we click on clear search button default value is vanished but it sets to another column default value.

```
$(".clearsearchclass", tr).click(function () {
                  var ptr = $(this).parents("tr:first"),
                  coli = parseInt($("td.ui-search-oper", ptr).attr('colindex'), 10),
                  sval = $.extend({}, $t.p.colModel[coli].searchoptions || {}),
                  dval = sval.defaultValue ? sval.defaultValue : "",
                  elem;
```

In case of re order of columns the underlying HTML of header columns(th) not changed.i.e. colIndex of th td.ui-search-oper. In case of clear search text it gets wrong colindex of a column but $t.p.colModel[coli].searchoption is updated to new column structure. ColIndex remain sets to one value and due to this dval sets to another column default value

We need both column reorder and filter toolbar functionality and in case of clear search text the value should be vanished and not set to wrong column default value.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI6Bc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c80Q1.png)

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a bug. If you are a licensed user, please post the problem in the appropriate [place here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4) or e-mail to the Guriddo support team.  It is much better to post bugs in the right place

Comment: The problem is fixed. Please try with the fixed version.

Comment: Thank you Tony for a quick fix. We have incorporated this fix in our code and its working fine but we have observed another behavior, when we had cleared the filter text on columns and click on advanced search the default filter criteria remains there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You know what is the way of fixing bugs